# reducers get Function not Object in redux, what's wrong with it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I got a error at my react and redux project. and I not found how to resolve it.

this is error message:

`The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Function". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "posts", "sidebar"`

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d66v5.png)

codes:

store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import reducers from '../reducers/index'

const middleware = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [ thunk ] : [ thunk, logger() ]

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware),  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)

export default store
```

reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import posts from './posts'
import sidebar from './sidebar'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts,
    sidebar
})

export default rootReducer
```

reducers/posts.js:

```
import {
    RECEIVE_POSTS,
    RECEIVEING_POSTS
} from '../containers/index'

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: {},
    message: 'done'
}

const post = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                posts: action.posts
            })
            break
        case RECEIVEING_POSTS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                message: 'loading'
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default post
```

reducers/sidebar.js

```
import {
    TOGGLE_SIDEBAR
} from '../containers/index'

const initialState = {
    show: true
}

const sidebar = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_SIDEBAR:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                show: ! state.show
            })
            break
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default sidebar
```

I read redux example but I don't know what's wrong with my code. It just throw Error.

Those code is very like redux example!!!

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Could you post the content of your `sidebar` file ?

Comment: Ok, I added `sidebar` code. but this file just like `posts`. If I remove the sidebar at `combineReducers`. I got same error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the old that used to work:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware),  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
```

Now you have to convert it to:

```
const store = redux.createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    redux.compose(
        redux.applyMiddleware(...middleware),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that...

the params that **second** at `createStore` is `initialState`, **not** middleware..

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the keys of your state object must match that of the object you passed to `combineReducers`. Check this doc for more details [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html)

Comment: I know that. `state` sent to reducers is local state, not global. I want to know where exactly I am wrong. I really checkout redux example many times  but I don't know what should I do :(

Comment: Oh! I can see the error. You reducer function in `reducers/posts.js` should be `posts` not `post`