# React devToolsExtension breaks the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-devtools-extension

When I create a store using

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware),  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
```

I receive a warning in the console and the store doesn't work:

> The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of
>   "Function". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys:
>   "posts", "sidebar"

When I remove the `DevTools`

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

it starts working again.

Do you how to asign `DevTools` and have the app still working? If you'd like to see some sources have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37209491/1075289). It's configured in the pretty same manner as my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up my tools like this:

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            createLogger(),
            errorHandler,
            navigate,
            tracking
        ),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
);
```

Note the use of `compose` here, you import it from `redux` along with `applyMiddleware` and `createStore`.

IIRC your way of doing it used to work in an older version of `redux`, but I can't be certain exactly when it stopped working. I do remember having the same problem you had though.

Comment: correct! I'll accept the answer as soon as it's possible. Thank you!